# JSF <f:ajax> request not sent if value is changed through javascript

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following code in XHTML:

```
<h:inputText value="#{SearchAction.lat}" id="lat">
            <f:ajax event="valueChange"  listener="#{SearchAction.findAddress}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

If I change the content of the input field, the listener gets called correctly.

However, on page load I call a javascript function that populates the input field with a new value and I could see the input field being populated but the ajax request doesn't get sent to the server.

Is there a distinction between user-provided values and javascript provided values?

-Majid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to programmatically invoke the `change` event afterwards in JS.

```
inputElement.change();
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Here is How I invoked the event: 
`var elem = document.getElementById("search_form:lat");
            if (typeof elem.onchange == "function") {
                elem.onchange.apply(elem);
            }`